# How to solve Memory Error and speed up the method in Sympy?

Tags: python, out-of-memory, sympy, numerical-methods

I am doing Runge-Kutta method, with controlling step by stability, accuracy, and from other numerical method - to prevent transition beyond the switching point.

When the step is small(by accuracy or other method), integrating lasts long, and I got memory error, like this

```
line 712, in _getitem_RepMatrix
    return self._rep.getitem_sympy(index_(i), index_(j))
TypeError: 'slice' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 157, in extract
    row2[j2] = row1_j1
MemoryError
```

So, it happens, when I need accuracy about 1E-5 or 1E-6 and more.

The main built of method

```
def rkf2stepcontrol(
        matrix_size,
        dydx, A, x, b, dxdt, hn, t, tout, eps, predicate_func, MatrixForYacobian, hstabilitygetting, halgebraic):

        k1 = zeros(matrix_size, 1)
        k2 = zeros(matrix_size, 1)
        k3 = zeros(matrix_size, 1)
        k2k1norm = zeros(matrix_size, 1)
        while ((predicate_func == False) or (tout - t > eps)):

            print('Current time', t)
            b = t
            iterations += 1
            print("I am in point ", x)

            xprint_s = xprint_s.col_insert(1, Matrix([x]))

            k1 = hn * dxdt(A, x, b)

            print(k1, 'k1')


            for i in (range(matrix_size)):
                k2[i, 0] = hn * dxdt(A, x + k1[i, 0] * sympy.ones(*x.shape), b)[i, 0]


            xold = x


            for i in (range(matrix_size)):
                x[i, 0] = x[i, 0] + 0.5 * (k1[i, 0] + k2[i, 0])
```

Then, controlling step by accuracy solving the equation 0.5‖k1-k2 ‖≤eps, where k2 and k1 - method steps and eps - needed accuracy. And controlling stability by getting max(abs(Jacobian Matrix.eigenvalues)

All the values will be shown on plot, so I must contain them.

Comment: Your interface, as far as visible, is a strange mix of generality and specialization. It appears that you do not implement the Fehlberg method here, but the Heun method with embedded Euler method? There are no per-coordinate slope functions, you understood something wrong in the step from methods for scalar ODE to methods for systems of ODE.

Comment: I forgot the big question: Why sympy? You do not even need scipy, all operations can be done in numpy.

Comment: No, it is not a Heun method. Eiler method is using separately, it integrates the same system, but manualy. and it is controlling the step by Newton's method, to prevent  prevent transition beyond the switching point.

Like this 


while g>eps:
...
 hp = (gamma-1)*ystartlinearelersecondvarstep[2, 0]/(-3 * VYold - 9.81 + VYold)
...
return ystartlineareler_discrete_print_variablstep, endtime_eilermethodvariablestep,h_for_output

And we get h_for_output[-1] as algebraic step and starting step in main Runge-Kutta method.

Comment: Sympy allows to work with matrices more simply. I tried numpy, and then transited to sympy.

Comment: The Swiss mathematician with a long stay in Berlin and St. Petersburg is Leonard Euler. // If you need sympy for matrix calculations and not for symbolic algebra you are doing something wrong. // And what do you mean by "switching point", is that specific to the ODE you want to solve or do you mean "crossing the boundary of the stability region"?

Comment: Imagine we are modeling the falling ball. We need to find the moment, where it touches the ground, so when the height coordinate is zero. Most modeling tools use dichotomy method, but it is going through transition point. So we go UNDER ground, under zero. But imagine, we have to searching roots in equation. There is no root of negative. This is it. And, after transition point we will have different ODE system, that controls behaviour of system.

Comment: Ok, yes. That is ODE specific. This is an event, located at the root of an event function. Some packages provide action-callbacks that can change the state, scipy's solve_ivp only provides a "terminate" action, so one has to change the state manually. // And yes, most event mechanisms look for a sign change in the event function and then refine that via some bracketing method like, at worst, the bisection method. // It is a *good* idea to continue with the unchanged system into the non-physical states, as that gives a smooth event function making event location easy.

Comment: So, only way is to rewrite everything on numpy, instead of sympy?

Comment: I would say yes. This should solve the speed problem to some extend. You should only need sympy if you manipulate symbolic expressions. In the context of numerical ODE solutions, this should end by transcribing the result in some evaluation procedures that are based on numpy, such as provided by the `lambdify` function. I can't imagine where one would apply symbolic transformations inside an integration step (except for (slow) prototypes of e.g. Taylor methods).

Comment: Thanks for your consultation. I don't have much time for this, but I will think.

Comment: You can use SymPy for this but the idea would be to symbolically derive the expressions that you want to evaluate in terms of symbols rather than numbers once at the beginning and then use `lambdify` to create a function that can efficiently evaluate those expressions many times numerically to be used for the numerical integration.

Comment: I am doing a layout for a numerical method, which will then be ported to Fortran. So I must not evaluate function, and doing it by symbolic, but actually do the integration numerically.

Comment: It might help to know what was wrong about `numpy` - but maybe that's something for another question.  Is that arrays can be 0d or 1d, as opposed to always being 2d?  Wayward MATLAB users are bothered by that, but I outgrew that years ago.  Bur you intend to transition to Fortran, may be you should start with MATLAB, or Octave is that's cheaper for you.  Or stick with Python and lists - if you aren't taking advantage of any compiled whole-array methods.

Comment: Wrong about numpy - not easy to do the same operations, as I do here, getting and work with array with any size(actually,  NxN, otherwise, there is no Jacobian Matrx). Doing it in Fortran wouldn't be my job. I must do this, and in Python.

Comment: With sympy, it was easier with row_insert, row_del, column_insert, col_del, this like this, k2[i, 0] = hn * dxdt(A, x + k1[i, 0] * sympy.ones(*x.shape), b)[i, 0] . Also, indexing, @hpauji

Comment: It's been a while since I used Fortran, and that was in early versions that didn't have powerful matrix functions.  But being a compiled language, growing and shrinking matrices on-the-fly isn't easy.  Space for matrices is allocated at the start of code,  not dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to numpy gives some speed up, but still too long, if you use accuracy about 1E-5 or 1E-6. With 1E-4, it takes 55 minutes to integrate 2.37 seconds, so about an hour to make 2.5 seconds. And, you need to recalculate accuracy only by condition 0.5‖k1-k2 ‖≤eps.

Code rewrited as
...

```
k1 = numpy.zeros((matrix_size, 1))
k2 = numpy.zeros((matrix_size, 1))
k3 = numpy.zeros((matrix_size, 1))
k2k1norm = numpy.zeros((matrix_size, 1))
xprint_s = numpy.c_[xprint_s, x]
k1 = hn * dxdt(A, x, b)
for i in (range(matrix_size)):
        k2[i, 0] = hn * dxdt(A, x + k1[i, 0] * numpy.ones(x.shape,dtype=float,order='C'), b)[i, 0]



for j in range(matrix_size):            
    k2k1norm[j, 0] = float(dxdt(A, x + k1[i, 0] * numpy.ones(x.shape,dtype=float,order='C'), b)[j, 0]) - \
                                 float(dxdt(A, x, b)[j, 0])
...
return iterations, endtime, xprint_s
```

And to make the plot

```
yprint_s_rkeiler_angle_step2 = numpy.delete(yprint_s_rkeiler_angle_step2, 0, -1) 
argument1 = list((yprint_s_rkeiler_angle_step2[0]))
argument2 = list((yprint_s_rkeiler_angle_step2[1]))
title('Runge Kutta Esposito Based on Eiler')
plot(t, argument1, '-o', linewidth=2)
plot(t, argument2, '-o', linewidth=2)
legend(["y", "Vy"], loc ="upper right")
print()
ylabel("argument")
xlabel("t")
grid(True)
show() # display
```